# Error converting XLTM to XLSX using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi, spring-batch

I'm want to convert an Excel XLTM file to XLSX format as part of a Spring-Batch step.  I'm using the following code to convert the file:

```
def convertXltmToXlsx(String oldFilename, String newFileName) {
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream(oldFilename));
    pkg.replaceContentType(
            "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.main+xml",
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
    pkg.save(out);
    out.close();
}
```

However, when I try to open the file (`converted.xlsx`) with Excel, I get the following message:

```
The file 'converted.xlsx' is a macro-free file, but contains macro-enabled content.
```

When I amend the code to print the content type of the old and new files by doing this:

```
def parts = pkg.getParts()
parts.each { part ->
    println "Part type: ${part.getContentType()}"
}

// do the conversion as before

OPCPackage newPkg = OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream(newFileName));
parts = newPkg.getParts()
parts.each { part ->
    println "New part type: ${part.getContentType()}"
}
```

I then get the following:

```
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/xml
Part type: application/xml
Part type: application/xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.custom-properties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.calcChain+xml
Part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawing+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.vmlDrawing
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml
Part type: application/vnd.ms-office.vbaProject
Part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.main+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml

New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/xml
New part type: application/xml
New part type: application/xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.customXmlProperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.custom-properties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.calcChain+xml
New part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.ms-excel.controlproperties+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.drawing+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.vmlDrawing
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.printerSettings
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml
New part type: application/vnd.ms-office.vbaProject
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
New part type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
```

How do I convert XLTM to XLSX please?

Comment: What happens if you also remove the Macro VBA part?

Comment: Same answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Next step, a bit more involved though - open the file in Excel, and save it as a .xlsx. Unzip both files (the .xls# formats are zip based), and compare, to see what other aspects get changed